# Create an array with enum element size

Tags: arrays, enums, rust

I want to create an array of a size specified by an element in an enum, like so:

```
pub use self::Register::*;

enum Register {
    Ip,
    Sp,
    NumRegs,
}

struct State {
    val: int,
    regs: [int; NumRegs as int],
    running: bool,
}
```

But I get:

```
src/main.rs:19:11: 19:32 error: expected constant expr for array length: non-constant path in constant expr
src/main.rs:19     regs: [int; NumRegs as int],
```

I've tried using `as int`, among other solutions, and Googled around for some time, but have not found a solution. Incidentally, is this bad form in Rust?

Comment: `enum`s don't semantically correspond to a numeric value, like you might expect if you come from C. Could you explain a bit more about what code you'd really like to have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, I don't think Rust is capable of seeing that `Enum::Variant` is effectively a constant (I don't actually know that it *is*, either), so it cannot be used as the array length. More than that, I would say that it's strange to add an enum variant that isn't actually intended to be used.

For how I see your problem, I'd probably try to represent your registers as a struct:

```
struct Registers {
    ip: u8,
    sp: u8,
}

struct State {
    val: u8,
    regs: Registers,
    running: bool,
}

fn main() {
    let s = State {
        val: 0,
        regs: Registers { ip: 0, sp: 0 },
        running: false,
    };
}
```

**Edit**

If you'd like to get a register by name, how about we do that directly:

```
struct Registers {
    ip: u8,
    sp: u8,
}

impl Registers {
    fn by_name(&self, name: &str) -> u8 {
        match name {
            "ip" => self.ip,
            "sp" => self.sp,
            _ => panic!("Unknown register '{}'", name),
        }
    }

    fn by_name_mut(&mut self, name: &str) -> &mut u8 {
        match name {
            "ip" => &mut self.ip,
            "sp" => &mut self.sp,
            _ => panic!("Unknown register '{}'", name),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut r = Registers { ip: 0, sp: 0 };

    println!("Instruction pointer: 0x{:02x}", r.by_name("ip"));
    *r.by_name_mut("ip") += 1;
    println!("Instruction pointer: 0x{:02x}", r.by_name("ip"));
}
```

Although that `panic!` right there is pretty ugly... I'd rather use an enum for that purpose. Let's do both the enum and the string:

```
use std::str::FromStr;

#[derive(Debug,Copy,Clone,PartialEq)]
enum Register {
    Ip,
    Sp,
}

impl FromStr for Register {
    type Err = ();

    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, ()> {
        match s {
            "ip" => Ok(Register::Ip),
            "sp" => Ok(Register::Sp),
            _ => Err(()),
        }
    }
}

struct Registers {
    ip: u8,
    sp: u8,
}

impl Registers {
    fn by_name(&self, name: Register) -> u8 {
        match name {
            Register::Ip => self.ip,
            Register::Sp => self.sp,
        }
    }

    fn by_name_mut(&mut self, name: Register) -> &mut u8 {
        match name {
            Register::Ip => &mut self.ip,
            Register::Sp => &mut self.sp,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut rs = Registers { ip: 0, sp: 0 };

    let r: Register = "ip".parse().unwrap();

    println!("Instruction pointer: 0x{:02x}", rs.by_name(r));
    *rs.by_name_mut(r) += 1;
    println!("Instruction pointer: 0x{:02x}", rs.by_name(r));
}
```

Now we have a nice clear separation between transitioning a string to our `Register` type, which means that only one part of our code has to deal with invalid register names (the call to `unwrap`).

Comment: Hi! I'm trying to make an array of registers that are indexable by enum so that I can do a simple reverse lookup by a string. Basically I don't want anything special about how I address a register. Not sure if that makes sense.

Comment: You can take a look at github.com/tekknolagi/carp/tree/master/src/ if you want. Similar design but perhaps there's a more idiomatic.

Comment: @tekknolagi, I've updated my answer to show how I would use strings to identify and then provide access to a specific register.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to reply. If I'm going to make a simple VM, is there any cleaner way to go about it? This seems a tiny bit clunky to me. Ignoring Carp for a second — what's the way you would create a small bytecode interpreter (at least this section of it)?

Comment: I don't really have any experience in the area of interpreters. Perhaps you can expand on what you find clunky? The big one I see is the duplication between `by_name` and `by_name_mut`, but it's possible a macro could help out there.

Comment: it's alright — I've decided to try and learn Rust better before trying again. Thank you for answering!